# Pygame window becomes unresponsive when the code is run

Tags: python, pygame

apologies for the long code. My problem is when I run the code and select option 2 in the menu the pygame window is launched however after a few seconds it becomes unresponsive. I have done a little bit of pygame before and have no idea what the problem is. Below is my code

```
import pygame, sys, time, random#Imports the modules pygame, sys, time and random form the python libary
from pygame.locals import *#Imports all of the pygame modules
global randomNumber
#randomNumber = random.randint(1,4)
redandBlackCounters = [120, 735, 250, 735, 560, 735, 690, 735]
pygame.init#Initiates the pygame modules
pygame.font.init()#Initites pygame fonts

class AQADO:#Defines a class called AQADO

    def Game_Board():#Defines a function called Game_Board
        global DISPLAYSURF#DISPLAYSURF is set to global so all functions can access it
        BOXSIZE = 70#Assigns 40 to the constant BOXSIZE
        GRIDSIZE = 11#Assigns 5 to the constant GRIDSIZE
        BOXLENGTH = 700#Assigns 700 to the constant BOXLENGTH

        G = (13,158,30)#Constant G is set to the colour green
        W = (255,255,255)#Constant W is set to the colour white
        B = (0,0,0)#Constant B is set to the colour black
        R = (245,10,10)#Constant R is set to the colour red

        WINDOW_X_MAX = BOXSIZE*GRIDSIZE#The constant WINDOW_X_MAX is BOXSIZE multiplyed by GRIDSIZE
        WINDOW_Y_MAX = 900#The constant WINDOW_X_MAX is BOXSIZE multiplyed by GRIDSIZE 
        DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_X_MAX, WINDOW_Y_MAX))
        pygame.display.set_caption("AQADo")#Sets the caption of the game window to AQADo

        DISPLAYSURF.fill(W)#fills the background white
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF,G,(BOXSIZE,0,BOXLENGTH,BOXSIZE))#draws a green rectangle at BOXSIZE, 0 length BOXLENGTH, width BOXSIZE
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF,G,(BOXSIZE,420,BOXLENGTH,BOXSIZE))#draws a green rectangle at BOXSIZE, 420 length BOXLENGTH, width BOXSIZE
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF,G,(BOXSIZE,700,BOXLENGTH,BOXSIZE))#draws a green rectangle at BOXSIZE, 700 length BOXLENGTH, width BOXSIZE
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF,B,(0,770,780,200))#draws a green rectangle at 0, 770 length 780, width 200

        for item in range (1, GRIDSIZE):#repeats below code 11 times
            pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, B, (0,item*BOXSIZE),(WINDOW_Y_MAX,item*BOXSIZE))#draws a line
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, B, (BOXSIZE,0), (BOXSIZE,WINDOW_X_MAX))#draws a line

        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, R,(redandBlackCounters[0],redandBlackCounters[1]),30)#draws a red circle at 120,735 with a radius of 30
        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, R,(redandBlackCounters[2],redandBlackCounters[3]),30)#draws a red circle at 250,735 with a radius of 30
        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, B,(redandBlackCounters[4],redandBlackCounters[5]),30)#draws a black circle at 560,735 with a radius of 30
        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, B,(redandBlackCounters[6],redandBlackCounters[7]),30)#draws a black circle at 690,735 with a radius of 30


    def call_Game_Board():#defines a function called call_Game_Board
        print("called the game board")
        AQADO.Game_Board()#returns function AQADO.Game_Board
        pygame.display.update()#Updates the pygame window

    #def Choose_Counters():
        #playerOneChoose = int(input("Please input 1 to move the red counter on the left or 2 to move the red counter one the right"))
        #if playerOneChoose == "1":
            #print("")
    def playerMove():
        if counter == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4:
            Check_Move()

    def Check_Move(counter):
        if redandBlackCounters[1,3,5,7] == 735 or 35 and randomNumber == 4:
            Counter_Move(move = False)
            print("move not possible")
        if redandBlackCounters[1] == 35 and redandBlackCounters[3] != 35 or 735 and randomNumber == 4:
            print("Counter 2 has to move one space back")
            redandBlackCounters[3] += 70
        if redandBlackCounters[3] == 35 and redandBlackCounters[1] != 35 or 735 and randomNumber == 4:
            print("Counter 1 has to move one space back")
            redandBlackCounters[1] += 70
        if redandBlackCounters[5] == 35 and redandBlackCounters[7] != 35 or 735 and randomNumber == 4:
            print("Counter 3 has to move one space back")
            redandBlackCounters[7] += 70
        if redandBlackCounters[7] == 35 and redandBlackCounters[5] != 35 or 735 and randomNumber == 4:
            print("Counter 4 has to move one space back")
            redandBlackCounters[5] += 70
        if redandBlackCounters[1,3] == 35:
            print(playerOne,"Wins")
        if redandBlackCounters[5,7] == 35:
            print(playerTwo,"Wins")
        #else:
            #Counter_Move(counter)

    def Counter_Move(redandBlackCounters, move, counter, randomNumber):
        if randomNumber == 1 and counter == 1 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[1] -= 70
            AQADO.Game_Board()#returns function AQADO.Game_Board
            pygame.display.update()#Updates the pygame window
            print("")
        if randomNumber == 1 and counter == 2 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[3] -= 70
            AQADO.Game_Board()#returns function AQADO.Game_Board
            pygame.display.update()#Updates the pygame window
            print("")
        if randomNumber == 1 and counter == 3 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[5] -= 70
            AQADO.Game_Board()#returns function AQADO.Game_Board
            pygame.display.update()#Updates the pygame window
            print("")
        if randomNumber == 1 and counter == 4 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[7] -= 70
            AQADO.Game_Board()#returns function AQADO.Game_Board
            pygame.display.update()#Updates the pygame window
            print("")

        if randomNumber == 2 and counter == 1 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[1] -= 140
            call_Game_Board()
            print("")
        if randomNumber == 2 and counter == 2 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[3] -= 140
            call_Game_Board()
            print("")
        if randomNumber == 2 and counter == 3 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[5] -= 140
            call_Game_Board()
            print("")
        if randomNumber == 2 and counter == 4 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[7] -= 140
            call_Game_Board()
            print("")

        if randomNumber == 3 and counter == 1 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[1] -= 210
            call_Game_Board()
            print("")
        if randomNumber == 3 and counter == 2 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[3] -= 210
            call_Game_Board()
            print("")
        if randomNumber == 3 and counter == 3 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[5] -= 210
            call_Game_Board()
            print("")
        if randomNumber == 3 and counter == 4 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[7] -= 210
            call_Game_Board()
            print("")

        if randomNumber == 4 and counter == 1 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[1] += 70
            call_Game_Board()
            print("")
        if randomNumber == 4 and counter == 2 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[3] += 70
            call_Game_Board()
            print("")
        if randomNumber == 4 and counter == 3 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[5] += 70
            call_Game_Board()
            print("")
        if randomNumber == 4 and counter == 4 and move != False:
            redandBlackCounters[7] += 70
            call_Game_Board()
            print("")

    def safe_Move():
        safe = 0
        if redandBlackCounters[1,3,5] != 735 or 435 and redandBlackCounters[1,3] == redandBlackCounters[5]: 
            safe = 1
        if redandBlackCounters[1,3,7] != 735 or 435 and redandBlackCounters[1,3] == redandBlackCounters[7]:
            safe = 2
        if redandBlackCounters[5,7,1] != 735 or 435 and redandBlackCounters[5,7] == redandBlackCounters[1]:
            safe = 3
        if redandBlackCounters[5,7,3] != 735 or 435 and redandBlackCounters[5,7] == redandBlackCounters[3]:
            safe = 4

    def Game_Function(playerOne, playerTwo):
        while True:#while True is equal to True
            AQADO.Game_Board()#returns AQADO.Game_Board function
            pygame.display.update()#Updates the pygame window
            for event in pygame.event.get():#checks for events in the pygame window
                if event.type == QUIT:#if event is quit
                    pygame.quit()#pygame is quit
                    sys.exit()#code is exited
                dieRoll = input("Please input r to roll the die")
                if dieRoll == "r":#If the key pressed is r
                    randomNumber = 1#random.randint(1,4)#random number between 1 and 4 is generated and set to variable randomNumber
                    #if randomNumber == 1:
                        #player_Information(playerInfo = 1, player = playerOne)
                    #if randomNumber == 2:
                        #player_Information(playerInfo = 2, player = playerOne)
                    #if randomNumber == 3:
                        #player_Information(playerInfo = 3, player = playerOne)
                   #if randomNumber == 4:
                        #player_Information(playerInfo = 4, player = playerOne)
                    counterInput = int(input("Which counter do you want to move 1 or 2?"))
                    if counterInput == "1":
                        AQADO.Counter_Move(redandBlackCounters, move, randomNumber, counter = 1)
                    if counterInput == "2":
                        AQADO.Counter_Move(redandBlackCounters, move, randomNumber, counter = 2)
                dieRoll = input("Please input a to roll the die")
                if dieRoll == "a":
                    randomNumber = 1
                    counterinput = int(input("Which counter do you want to move 3 or 4?"))
                    if counterInput == "3":
                        AQADO.Counter_Move(redandBlackCounters, move, randomNumber, counter = 3)
                    if counterInput == "4":
                        AQADO.Counter_Move(redandBlackCounters, move, randomNumber, counter = 4)

def player_Information(playerInfo, player): #This function prints the value of the dice roll as well as the player's name, it parses the variables playerInfo
    W = (255,255,255)                                                                                                                        #and player
    diceInformation = ["rolled a 1, move one of your pieces 1 space nearer to FINISH", "rolled a 2, move on of your pieces 2 spaces nearer to FINISH", 
                        "rolled a 3, move one of your oieces 3 spaces nearer to FINNISH", "rolled a 4, move one of your pieces 1 space back toward START"]
    #Defines an array called diceInformation which stores the text which is blitted to the screen
    if playerInfo == 1:#if player eqauls 11                                                                                    
        turnOne = (player, diceInformation[0])#turnOne is set to player, and index 0 of diceInformation
    if playerInfo == 2:#if player eqauls 12 
        turnOne = (player, diceInformation[1])#turnOne is set to player, and index 1 of diceInformation
    if playerInfo == 3:#if player eqauls 13 
        turnOne = (player, diceInformation[2])#turnOne is set to player, and index 2 of diceInformation
    if playerInfo == 4:#if player eqauls 14 
        turnOne = (player, diceInformation[3])#turnOne is set to player, and index 3 of diceInformation

    font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 20)#Sets the font and font size
    turnOne = font.render(str(turnOne),True,W)#Sets what text is blitted to the screen an the colour of the text
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(turnOne,(100, 800))#Sets the coordinates where the text is blitted and blits the code to the screen
    pygame.display.update()#Updates the pygame window
    pygame.time.wait(1000)#freezes the pygame window for 1000 miliseconds (1 second)


#def safe_Space(safeSpace, redandBlackCounters):#Defines a function called safe_Space which is passed the variable safeSpace and array redandBlackCounters
    #if safeSpace == 1:#if safe Space is equal to 1                  
        #if redandBlackCounters[1] and redandBlackCounters[5] != 735 and redandBlackCounters[1] == 455 and redandBlackCounters[5] or redandBlackCounters[7] == 455:
            #print("Safe")
        #elif redandBlackCounters[1] and redandBlackCounters[5] != 735 and redandBlackCounters[1] == redandBlackCounters[5]:
            #print("1")
            #redandBlackCounters[5] = 735#blackCounterOneY is set to 735
            #AQADO.call_Game_Board()#returns function call_Game_Board in the class AQADO
        #elif redandBlackCounters[1] and redandBlackCounters[7] != 735 and redandBlackCounters[1] == redandBlackCounters[7]:
            #print("2")
            #blackCounterTwoY = 735#blackCounterTwoY is set to 735
            #AQADO.call_Game_Board()#returns function call_Game_Board in the class AQADO
    #if safeSpace == 2:
        #if redandBlackCounters[1] and redandBlackCounters[5] != 735 and redandBlackCounters[1] == 455 and redandBlackCounters[5] or redandBlackCounters[7] == 455:
            #print("Safe")
        #if redandBlackCounters[1] and redandBlackCounters[5] != 735 and redandBlackCounters[1] == redandBlackCounters[5]:
            #print("1")
            #redandBlackCounters[1] = 735#redCounterOneY is set to 735
            #AQADO.call_Game_Board()#returns function call_Game_Board in the class AQADO
        #elif redandBlackCounters[1] and redandBlackCounters[7] != 735 and redandBlackCounters[1] == redandBlackCounters[7]:
            #print("2")
            #redandBlackCounters[3] = 735#redCounterTwoY is set to 735
            #AQADO.call_Game_Board()#returns function call_Game_Board in the class AQADO

def Menu():#Defines a function called Menu
    menu = ["\nThis is AQADo", "1 - Enter player names", "2 - Play game"]#Defines an array called menu
    menuLastItem = ["3 - Quit"]#Defines an array called menuLastItem
    for items in menu:#Prints all the itmes in the array menu
        print(items)

    return(menuLastItem[0])#Returns the index 0 in menuLastItem

##################################################################  MAIN CODE  #

option = 0 #Sets the variable option to 0
playerOne = 0 #Sets the variable playerOne to 0
playerTwo = 0 #Sets the variable PlayerTwo to 0
blackCounterOne = True
redCounterOne = True
playerTurn = 0
counter = 0
move =0
redandBlackCounters = [120, 735, 250, 735, 560, 735, 690, 735]
while option != 3:#When option is not 3 the while loop ends
    menuTwo = ["Please input 1,2 or 3 ", "Please enter a valid data type, 1,2 or 3","\nYou have exited the game"]#Defines an array called menuTwo
    menuSelectorItems = ["Please input player one's name ", "Please input player Two's name "]#Defines an array called menuSelectorItems
    print(Menu())#The function Menu is returned
    try:#Tries all of the inputs below for a keyboard interrupt
        try: #Tries menuSelector for an input which is not 1,2 or 3
            menuSelector = input(menuTwo[0])#Prints the string at index 0 in the array menuTwo
        except:#If menuSelector does not equal 1,2 or 3 then the menu is printed again 
             print(menuTwo[1],option)

        if menuSelector == "1":#If menuSelector equals 1 the players have to enter thier names
            playerOneName = input(menuSelectorItems[0])#Prints the string at index 0 in the array menuSelectorItems

            if playerOneName.isalnum():#If the input playerOneName equals alphnumeric then playerOne is set to playerOneName
                playerOne = playerOneName
            else:
                playerOne = "Player One"

            playerTwoName = input(menuSelectorItems[1])#Prints the string at index 1 in the array menuSelectorItems

            if playerOneName.isalnum(): #If the input playerTwoName equals alphnumeric then playerTwo is set to playerTwoName
                playerTwo = playerTwoName
            else:
                playerTwo = "Player Two"

        if menuSelector == "2":#If menuSelector equals 2 the function AQADo is returned
            if playerOne == 0:#If the playerOne equals 0 then playerOne is set to Player_One
                playerOne = "Player One"
            if playerTwo == 0: #If the playerTwo equals 0 then playerTwo is set to Player_Two
                playerTwo = "Player Two"
            AQADO.Game_Function(playerOne,playerTwo)#returns function AQADo in class AQADO and passes the variables playerOne and playerTwo

        if menuSelector == "3": #If menuSelector equals 3 the code is exited
            print(menuTwo[2])#Prints the string at index 2 in the array menuTwo
            option = 3 #Sets the variable option to 3
            pygame.quit()#Closes the pygame window
            sys.exit()#Exits the code

    except KeyboardInterrupt:#If there is a keyboard interrupt
        print(menuTwo[2])#Prints the string at index 2 in the array menuTwo
        pygame.quit()#Closes the pygame window
        sys.exit()#Exits the code if there is a keyboard interrupt
```

Comment: See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you check the events of pygame, you wrote following code:

```
dieRoll = input("Please input r to roll the die")
```

...wich stops the program until you type something into the console and press Enter.

As a consequence, the events ("pygame.event.get()") don't get pulled anymore. This makes your operating-system think that the program is broken. (In Windows, the window becomes white and the cursor a hourglass)

I suggest to use the [pygame.key](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html)-Module instead of the console.

**Edit:**

In your case, you want to roll the die only *once* per "button-push", so you'd better use 
the pygame.event-module to get the key. Here is an example:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_r:  #If key "r" gets (not is) pressed
        roll_die()
```

This way, the "roll_die()" part gets executed only *once* if you press the "r"-key. Otherwise, with the pygame.key-module, every frame the "r"-key is pressed, your code get's executed again
(usefull in other situations of course, but not here).

Why that is and how this works you can read by yourself on the doc-pages of [pygame.key](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) and [pygame.event](httP://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html). It's actually pretty well described.

Comment: It works! I just need to get my counters to move, thanks for the help